# Minimum launching speed projectile constraint

Tags: kinematics, projectile

I came across an interesting lemma in page-9 of [Jaan Kalda's Kinematics handouts](https://www.ioc.ee/%7Ekalda/ipho/kin_ENG.pdf), the following is written:

> When a target is shot with the smallest possible
> launching speed, the trajectory and the shooting range boundary (corresponding to the launching speed) are tangent to each
> other at the target’s position.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I don't understand the statement in bold.  For minimum possible launching speed, if your projectile lands at the same elevation that it was launched from, you have to shoot the projectile at a 45 degree angle.  Can you include a drawing showing the physical situation?

Comment: Hi , its Fact 7 on pg 9 in Jaan Kalda's IPhO notes for Kinematics: https://www.ioc.ee/~kalda/ipho/kin_ENG.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a trajectory touches the shooting range boundary, the two curves must be tangent. Otherwise, if you extend the trajectory in one direction, you can surpass the shooting range boundary.

When the projectile is launched with minimal speed and still hits the target, the target should lie on the shooting range boundary. If the target is outside the boundary, it is impossible to hit the target; if the target is inside the boundary, a slower launching speed can be used.

Using these two facts, we can show the desired lemma.